# ExceptionFilter asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date

I am going to create own `exceptionfilter` which was inherit from `FilterAttribute` and `IExceptionFilter`
Source code is given below :

```
public class IndexException : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
    {
        if (!exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled && exceptionContext.Exception is IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            exceptionContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Content/ExceptionFound.html");
            exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But when my code get to Index method where exception generated manually, my filter can't work

```
[IndexException]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    throw new Exception("Не может быть меньше нуля");
```

Comment: Try to add `[IndexException]` on controller instead of on method

Comment: if (!exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled && exceptionContext.Exception is IndexOutOfRangeException) -> the exception you are throwing from the action is not of type IndexOutOfRange and hence will not go insode the if condition

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your filter `IndexException` in the ASP.NET MVC Pipeline via `RegisterGlobalFilters` in **`FilterConfig.cs`**.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        // add your filter
        filters.Add(new IndexException());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception filter will only redirect to the `ExceptionFound.html` if a `IndexOutOfRangeException` is caught.In the example you provided you are throwing a generic `Exception`.

Either change your filter to catch all types of exceptions or change this line:

```
throw new Exception("Не может быть меньше нуля");
```

To this:

`throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Не может быть меньше нуля");`